# Setting Symfony project having Sylius Installation gives error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, sylius

On running `bin/console sylius:install` it gives below error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "sylius.model.shop_user.class". in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag.php:102

Comment: Maybe you can precise context, version, etc... We can't guess :/